# Create a sub query for sum data as a new column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Suppose that I have a table name as tblTemp which has data as below:

```
|  ID | AMOUNT |
----------------
|   1 |     10 |
| 1-1 |     20 |
| 1-2 |     30 |
| 1-3 |     40 |
|   2 |     50 |
|   3 |     60 |
|   4 |     70 |
| 4-1 |     80 |
|   5 |     90 |
|   6 |    100 |
```

- ID will be format as X (without dash) if it's only one ID or (X-Y) format if new ID (Y) is child of (X).

I want to add a new column (Total Amount) to output as below:

```
|  ID | AMOUNT |   Total Amount |
---------------------------------
|   1 |     10 |        100     |
| 1-1 |     20 |        100     |
| 1-2 |     30 |        100     |
| 1-3 |     40 |        100     |
|   2 |     50 |         50     |
|   3 |     60 |         60     |
|   4 |     70 |        150     |
| 4-1 |     80 |        150     |
|   5 |     90 |         90     |
|   6 |    100 |        100     |
```

- The "Total Amount" column is the calculate column which  sum value in Amount column that the (X) in ID column is the same.
- In order to get parent ID (X), I use the following SQL:

> ```
> SELECT
>   ID, SUBSTRING (ID, 1,
>       IIF (CHARINDEX('-', ID) = 0,
>           len(ID),
>           CHARINDEX('-', ID) - 1)
>   ), Amount
> FROM
>   tblTemp
> ```

How Can I query like this in SQL Server 2012?

You can use [sqlfiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/eb83a/1) to test it.

Thank You

Pengan

Answer (score 4):

You have already done most of the work. To get the final result you can use your existing query and make it a subquery or use a CTE, then use `sum() over()` to get the result:

```
;with cte as
(
  SELECT
    ID, 
    SUBSTRING (ID, 1, 
        IIF (CHARINDEX('-', ID) = 0,
            len(ID),
            CHARINDEX('-', ID) - 1) 
    ) id_val, Amount
  FROM tblTemp
)
select id, amount, sum(amount) over(partition by id_val) total
from cte
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/eb83a/14)

Comment: What do you think of the simpler `Left(ID, CharIndex('-', ID + '-') - 1)`?

Comment: @ErikE There are many ways to write this, I was just showing them how they could get the result with their existing query.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the `sum()` window function:

```
select id, amount,
       SUM(amount) over (partition by (case when id like '%-%'
                                            then left (id, charindex('-', id) - 1)
                                            else id
                                       end)
                        ) as TotalAmount
from tblTemp t
```

Comment: @Pengan . . . The `case` statement could also be replaced with the `iif` in the original query.  However, I'm a strong advocate of using ANSI standard functionality instead of database-specific functions (perhaps made even worse in this case because `iif` is from Access).